# How to get previous column index in an excel file using PHP?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

[image: array]

So I have this array and I'm trying to get the value of `"AA"` but since it is `null` I need to check if the previous index has data.

Most of the values are in `"AA"` except for this one.

How can I go back to the previous index?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I don't have any code yet, I'm currently working on it. I only have 1 variable which contains all the data of the excel file.

Comment: Can you explaine what do you mean with "previous index" ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini from "AA" to "Z" to "Y"... and so on until I get to "W" which has a value.

Comment: Can you delete null value so you can display the not empty variable : `print_r(array_filter($linksArray, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; }));`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Okay, I now have an array of values.